# Infinite stream from a video file (in a loop)

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, avconv

Is there any way howto create an infinite `h264` stream from a video file (eg. mp4, avi, ...). I'd like to use ffmpeg to transcode avi file to `h264` but there's no `loop` option for output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't. There is no such command in ffmpeg to loop video. You can use `-loop` for image only. If you are interested you can use concat demuxer. Create a playlist file e.g. playlist.txt

Inside playlist.txt add the video location

```
file '/path/to/video/video.mp4'
file '/path/to/video/video.mp4'
file '/path/to/video/video.mp4'
file '/path/to/video/video.mp4'
file '/path/to/video/video.mp4'
```

Run `ffmpeg`

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i playlist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

See [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12905/repeat-loop-input-video-with-ffmpeg)

Comment: you can loop video by either using a stream loop `-stream_loop` or a loop filter: `-filter_complex loop=repeat:size:start' for more info read the documentation on the [FFMPEG site](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loop)

Comment: There's also `movie=` which can loop, and works fine here.

Comment: While this answer is not incorrect (and a possible solution, especially if the last line of `playlist.txt` is `file playlist.txt` (thus providing an infinite loop), as @user2843110 has mentioned, you use `-stream_loop -1` to accomplish infinite looping of all kinds of streamable content — and **not** `-loop`.

Answer (score 25):

You should be able to use the `-stream_loop -1` flag *before* the input (`-i`):

```
ffmpeg -threads 2 -re -fflags +genpts -stream_loop -1 -i ./test.mp4 -c copy ./test.m3u8
```

The `-fflags +genpts` will regenerate the pts timestamps so it loops smoothly, otherwise the time sequence will be incorrect as it loops.

Comment: The stream_loop bug still happens.

Comment: Works fine on ffmpeg 3.3 Ubuntu 16.04 has 2.8 IIRC. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a live stream by looping a single video file then you could split it into .ts files and then simulate .m3u8 file with a php script which would return different .ts based on current time. You could try something similar to this:

```
<?php
// lets assume that we have stream splitted to parts named testXXXXX.ts
// and all parts have 2.4 seconds and we want to play in loop part
// from test0.ts to test29.ts forever in a live stream
header('Content-Type: application/x-mpegURL');
$time = intval(time() / 2.40000);
$s1 = ($time + 1) % 30;
$s2 = ($time + 2) % 30;
$s3 = ($time + 3) % 30;
$s4 = ($time + 4) % 30;
?>
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:2
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:<?php echo "$time\n"; ?>
#EXTINF:2.40000,
test<?php echo $s1; ?>.ts
<?php if ($s2 < $s1) echo "#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY\n"; ?>
#EXTINF:2.40000,
test<?php echo $s2; ?>.ts
<?php if ($s3 < $s2) echo "#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY\n"; ?>
#EXTINF:2.40000,
test<?php echo $s3; ?>.ts
<?php if ($s4 < $s3) echo "#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY\n"; ?>
#EXTINF:2.40000,
test<?php echo $s4; ?>.ts
```